# How Do I Get The Current Date As An Int?

Tags: android

I'm trying to find the difference between the current date and the user's selected date. However, it seems that I cannot get the current date.

```
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int curYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int curMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int curDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            Log.i("CurDay", String.valueOf(curDay));
            Log.i("HMMM", String.valueOf(dayOfMonth - curDay));





06-05 23:41:59.759 4366-4366/com.example.jackson.adhdagenda I/CurDay: 3
06-05 23:41:59.759 4366-4366/com.example.jackson.adhdagenda I/HMMM: 10
```

As an output I get that the curDay value is 3, which is not the date in the phone emulator. The date in my emulator is current. Why isn't it saying its '5'?

Comment: [You're welome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

`DAY_OF_WEEK` returns day within week. Where 1 indicates Sunday upto 7 which indicates Saturday. The value 3 you have received indicates Tuesday.

Instead of

`int curDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);`

USE

`int curDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
int curDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

use

```
int curDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
```